# (C++) multiplication wont give off expected results

Tags: c++

hello :) so this is my first time writing a c++ program, im currently using code::blocks tho im pretty sure the issue ive got probably isnt related to the program at all but anyway...

i want to write a simple code, where two "boxes" are created and their volume is calculated and printed on the terminal. ive written this code on a single cpp file:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box
{
public:
    double length;
    double breadth;
    double height;

    Box(double l, double b, double h)
    {
      l=length;
      b=breadth;
      h=height;
    }
};

int main()
{
    double volume = 0.0;
    Box BoxA(2.0, 3.2, 6.0);
    Box BoxB(2.5, 4.0, 5.0);
    volume = BoxA.length * BoxA.breadth * BoxA.height;
    cout << "Box a volume = " << volume <<endl;
    volume = BoxB.length * BoxB.breadth * BoxB.height;
    cout << "Box b volume = " << volume <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

so i build and run this thing, no errors but the results i get is this:

> box a volume = -0

//and sometimes =0

> box b volume = 0

but i dont understand what is wrong here. shouldnt the results be a=38.4 and b=50.0? what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: shouldn't `l=length;` etc. be `length=l;` instead?

Comment: In the constructor you are doing the assignment the wrong way!

Comment: Before you chose your accepted answer, I would like to mention that initializer lists should be preferred over assignment in constructors, in general. All member variables (as well as the base class(es)) are constructed in the constructor - either explicitly by using initializers or implicitly by the compiler using the default constructors of that. With assignment, this might become an unecessary default construction with following assignment. Not that significant for your 3 double member vars but maybe in other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor assigns values to the passed arguments.

Try this instead:

```
class Box
{
public:
    double length;
    double breadth;
    double height;

    Box(double l, double b, double h)
    {
      length=l;
      breadth=b;
      height=h;
    }
};
```

As others have mentioned, there are other improvements that can be made regarding initializer lists and the use of `using`, and the study of programming in general and c++ in particular is an ongoing journey, never a destination, but this is the direct fix for the immediate problem.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to write constructors is with initializer lists:

```
Box(double l, double b, double h) : length(l), breadth(b), height(h)
{
}
```

This prevent exactly the same error that you had, exchanging the argument and member. If you tried to write `: l(length),` the compiler would have told you straight away that `l` is not a member of `Box`.

You don't even need separate names with initializer lists:

```
Box(double length, double breadth, double height)  
    : length(length), breadth(breadth), height(height)
{ }
```

This does initialize `Box::height` with the argument `height`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>

class Box
{
public:
    double length;
    double breadth;
    double height;

    Box(double l, double b, double h)
    {
        length = l; // assign to the member variables, not parameters
        breadth = b;
        height = h;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    double volume = 0.0;

    Box BoxA(2.0, 3.2, 6.0);
    Box BoxB(2.5, 4.0, 5.0);

    volume = BoxA.length * BoxA.breadth * BoxA.height;
    std::cout << "Box a volume = " << volume << std::endl;

    volume = BoxB.length * BoxB.breadth * BoxB.height;
    std::cout << "Box b volume = " << volume << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the refined version of your code. Note that you shouldn't use namespace std. That's a bad programming practice.